# where can I find GladeGen?

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I'd like to design a GUI using Glade, and generate python code from it. The thing is, I can't find GladeGen. Does anyone know where it can be downloaded from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the GUI designer is something like Anjuta or the Glade program, write that out to **glade XML** and use the python bindings for libglade to use the XML file ... Kind of like XAML.

**Edit, added some links to Glade.xml->python**

http://glc.sourceforge.net/
http://www.pygtk.org/ (might help)

Comment: Last commit to `glc` in sourceforge csv seems to have been in 2002; there is also [Glade Code Generator - gcgen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcgen/files/) with last update 2010, which needs an extra XML library that it packages...

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7558

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is - don't generate code. Glade 3.6 can now save in the GtkBuilder format (xml), which can be loaded in your code. This is much easier to deal with!

http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkbuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been copied to this Bazaar repository in launchpad:

[launchpad.net/~wattazoum: gladegen : Code : Python dev tools](https://code.launchpad.net/~wattazoum/pydevtools/gladegen)

(direct [download tarball](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~wattazoum/pydevtools/gladegen/tarball/3?start_revid=3) - used this for the snippet below)

Also, the links to the article by the author of GladeGen:

- [Rapid Application Development with Python and Glade | Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7421)
- [Resources for “Rapid Application Development with Python and Glade” | Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7558)

Note that in Glade 3.8.0, you can export files as either `Libglade` or `GtkBuilder`; I made a little test which shows you should save the files as Libglade; GladeGen can parse both:

```
$ python2.7 GladeGen.py /tmp/test-libglade.glade TestMe TestMe
funcs
main <function main at 0xb72d98b4>
search_file <function search_file at 0xb72d964c>

classes
GladeWindow <class 'GladeWindow.GladeWindow'>
TestMe <class 'TestMe.TestMe'>

methods
('GladeWindow', '__init__')
('GladeWindow', 'hide')
('GladeWindow', 'set_callback_function')
('GladeWindow', 'set_search_path')
('GladeWindow', 'set_top_window')
('GladeWindow', 'show')
('TestMe', '__init__')
('TestMe', 'hide')
('TestMe', 'init')
('TestMe', 'set_callback_function')
('TestMe', 'set_search_path')
('TestMe', 'set_top_window')
('TestMe', 'show')

widgets
('GtkWindow', 'window1')
('GtkHBox', 'hbox1')
('GtkScrolledWindow', 'scrolledwindow1')

handlers

$ python2.7 GladeGen.py /tmp/test-gtkbuilder.glade TestMe2 TestMe2
funcs
main <function main at 0x95778ec>
search_file <function search_file at 0x9577684>

classes
GladeWindow <class 'GladeWindow.GladeWindow'>
TestMe2 <class 'TestMe2.TestMe2'>

methods
('GladeWindow', '__init__')
('GladeWindow', 'hide')
('GladeWindow', 'set_callback_function')
('GladeWindow', 'set_search_path')
('GladeWindow', 'set_top_window')
('GladeWindow', 'show')
('TestMe2', '__init__')
('TestMe2', 'hide')
('TestMe2', 'init')
('TestMe2', 'set_callback_function')
('TestMe2', 'set_search_path')
('TestMe2', 'set_top_window')
('TestMe2', 'show')

widgets

handlers
```

However, if you try to run the exported python code, only the first (`python TestMe.py`) will run; while the second, gtkbuilder one, will fail:

```
$ python2.7 TestMe2.py

(TestMe2.py:24883): libglade-WARNING **: Expected <glade-interface>.  Got <interface>.

(TestMe2.py:24883): libglade-WARNING **: did not finish in PARSER_FINISH state
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestMe2.py", line 66, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "TestMe2.py", line 59, in main
    w = TestMe2()
  File "TestMe2.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "TestMe2.py", line 52, in init
    GladeWindow.__init__(self, filename, top_window, widget_list, handlers)
  File "/path/to/src/wattazoum_pydevtools_gladegen/src/GladeWindow.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.xml = gtk.glade.XML(fname)
RuntimeError: could not create GladeXML object
```

Well, I'm just glad I can still use this, as apparently it is not possible for Glade to generate / export / create / save-as Python code ...

---

... EDIT: although, it should be noted that the export is just:

```
def init(self):
  filename = '/tmp/test-libglade.glade'
  widget_list = [
          'window1',
          'hbox1',
          'scrolledwindow1',
          ]
  handlers = [
          ]
  top_window = 'window1'
  GladeWindow.__init__(self, filename, top_window, widget_list, handlers)
```

... that is, it just interfaces to the glade file (pretty much as in the starting tutorial http://www.pygtk.org/articles/pygtk-glade-gui/Creating_a_GUI_using_PyGTK_and_Glade.htm), and it doesn't actually create python code that I expected, as in translated code, like:

```
self.window1 = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
```

... and so on... which is a shame, because that was what I was otherwise looking for `:)`